# Can't assign range using .End(xlDown) in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, range, variable-assignment, excel-2003, vba

I've inherited some VBA code (non-.NET, Excel 2003) I have to modify. I want to obtain a handle on a cell range but VBA doesn't like my syntax, saying 'Run-time error 424: Object required'.

When running this code it highlights the line assigning `streamsTotal`.

```
Private Sub totalStreams()

    Dim streams As Range, streamsTotal As Range

    ' Select streams data range
    Set streams = Range("H8").End(xlDown)

    ' reference cell 2 cells below last stream row
    Set streamsTotal = streams.Offset(2, 0)

End Sub
```

I'm struggling to find my answer in Google and previous questions here. Thanks.

Comment: Just so you know, in VBA if you do this: Dim streams, streamsTotal As Range

You have actually declared streams as a Variant. You might want:
Dim streams As Range, streamsTotal As Range

Comment: Thanks, I assumed they were both Range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the cell range I was attempting to select was empty.